# Where is the SHARE button in Firefox 80 (2020?

Tags: firefox, sharing, firefox-extensions

There used to be a share button on the menu bar where you could share web pages directly with someone.  It would ask you how you wanted to share and offer any app that was set up in Firefox (ie Gmail).  After you used a certain app over and over, that app would be the default and show right next to the share button.

I'm not looking to share any Facebook Stuff - I know how to do that if I want to.  I want to send birthday present ideas and news articles. Where is the share button?

Comment: The three dots `...` right to the right of the webpage address allow you to Copy Link, Email Link, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Click on the 3 dots as shown in the graphic and you will be presented with a new menu:

[image]

Make your selection from the available options.

UPDATE v89:
To add the envelope for `Email Link` you need to click on the hamburger menu (three parallel lines) on the address bar, select `More Tools` then `Customise ToolBar`. You will be presented with a graphical representation of the additional items you can select and you can either drag to the toolbar or right click on the ones you want and select `Add to Toolbar`.

[image]

Comment: Not seeing the dots for some reason on Firefox 89.0.2, MacOS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: @ChrisSmith This has now changed since version 89 and I have now updated my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Thanks though none of these replace the 3 dots really. Not sure why Mozilla made this change.

Comment: @ChrisSmith I'm not sure you have grasped the point. None of the items shown are intended to replace the 3 dots... just that access to the additional tools for inclusion on the tool bar are now, by convention, contained within the hamburger menu.

Comment: Yeah must be misunderstanding each other. I found the solution I was looking for though: just right click the tab and the equivalent “share” options are in the context menu. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right click the tab > click "Share"

[image]